# What is the difference in meaning between "in church," "at church", "in a church" and "at a church"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentence?

> I am in church.
>
> I am in a church.
>
> I am at church.
>
> I am at a church.

I am aware that *in a church* means being inside the building called church. And being at church can mean  near a church or inside church. And being at church means being in attendance in your local church. What is the difference between *in church* and *at church*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*In* church" and "*at* church" both idiomatically mean that you are *attending a church service*. It may also be assumed that you are at the church you normally attend. The word "church" can refer to a specific building, but it can also refer to the religious organisation as a whole.

"In *a* church" means that you inside a church building. As it uses the indefinite article, it could be any church building at all.

"At a church" means you are in the general vicinity of a church building - possibly inside it, but possibly just outside. Again, it could be any church.