# Use "would" and "could" to express possibility or politeness: do we need to change tenses in the subordinate clauses?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditionals

According to https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm, *would* can be used to create remoteness of possibility or probability remoteness between speakers (formality, politeness).

Here are examples by me that try to create remoteness of possibility or probability or remoteness between speakers as the site says we can.

---

***Would* examples:**

(1) If you want my answer, I would think that I will give you some.

(2) I would expect him to come because he doesn't seem to be busy.

(3) I saw him jogging this morning. He would seem to be getting better if he is able to go jogging now.

(4) You have the correct answer. Well, I would have to agree with you if you have the correct answer.

(5) It's Christmas. She would go to the church when people celebrate Christmas on the streets.

---

***Could* examples:**

(6) If you want my answer, I could give you some.

(7) I could expect him to come because he doesn't seem to be busy these days.

(8) I saw him jogging this morning. He could get better soon if he is able to go jogging now.

(9) You have the correct answer. Well, I could agree with you if you have the correct answer.

(10) It's Christmas. She could be at the church when people celebrate Christmas on the streets.

---

**My questions:**

(a) Can we use them this way?

(b) Do we just treat *would* and *could* as softer *will* and *can* when using them for these purposes?

(c) And even though *would* and *could* are in past tense, we don't need to change the tense in subordinate clauses and we just use the tenses in the subordinate clauses according to what we try to say, right?

Comment: Your 'would' examples are OK, though I don't quite understand the intended meaning of No. 5. The 'could' sentences don't work so well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will rewrite (5) to: She goes to the church often. She could be at the church when people hang out on the streets on the Christmas Day. Is it ok to use "would" here? In terms of the "could" examples, are they technically correct usage to express possibility but just not very idiomatic? How about using "could probably" in the "could" examples?

Comment: "She goes _to church_ often. She could [well] be at/in church when [other] people are hanging out on the streets on Christmas Day." See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230979/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-in-church-at-church-in-a-church)

Comment: _Could_ has the implication 'it would be possible if you wish for it'. (7) and (9) don't really make sense. (8) would be better expressed as "He could/must be getting better/on the road to recovery if he is able to go jogging". "He could get better soon if he is able to go jogging" sounds as though you think jogging is his only possibility for recovery!

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for you replies. They are very helpful. Short questions. Does (5) make sense this way with "would"? => "She goes to the church often. She would be at the church when people hang out on the streets on the Christmas Day." And What is the use of "well" in your revised sentence? Does it mean "reasonably"?

Comment: If you mean that she attends services, it's _goes to church_ (see the link I provided). _Could well be = is likely to be_. _Would_ doesn't fit with the present tense. "She would be at church when other people _were_ hanging out." - but that isn't the conditional.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. If I am not sure whether Mike can eat a lot, can I tell my others, "If Mike eats at an all-you-can-eat restaurant, he 'would' pig out on every kind of food there"? I use the "would" in the sentence to express the uncertainty or possibility because I don't want to sound assertive. Is that correct usage?

Comment: "If he eats... he will..."  "If he were to eat... he would..."

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I understand the usages of the conditionals you mentioned. However, you said "would" can be used to express uncertainty or possibility in your previous comments. How is "If Mike eats at an all-you-can-eat restaurant, he 'would' pig out on every kind of food there" different?

Comment: _Would_ has to match the tense of the verb in the if-clause. You could use 'If he ate... he would...' as well.